# Regular Expression to Match Text into Mutliple Groups

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to set up a regular expression to match text and I'd like a particular string to match with a separate group from the rest of the text if it is present.

For instance, if my string is `this is a test`, I would like `this is a` to match the first group and `test` to match the second group. I am using the python regex library. Here are a few more examples of what result I would like

- `this is a test` - group 1: `this is a`, group 2: `test`
- `one day at a time` - group 1: `one day at a time`, group 2:
- `one day test is` - group 1: `one day`, group 2: `test`
- `testing, 1,2,3` - no match
- `this is not a drill` - group 1: `this is not a drill`, group 2:

in those cases, the particular string I'm matching in the second group is test. I'm not sure how to set up a regular expression to match these particular cases correctly.

Comment: `testis match` and `testing not match` add more explanation about that

Comment: That was a typo, I updated to correct that. But also, group 1 has to contain some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```
^(?:(?!test))(?:(.*)(?=\btest\b)(\btest\b)|(.*))
```

> Explanation

- `^(?:(?!test))` - Negative look ahead.Don't match anything start with test.
- `(.*)` - Matches anything except newline.
- `(?=\btest\b)` - Positive lookahead. Matches `test` between word boundaries.
- `(\btest\b)` - Capturing group matches `test`.
- `|` - Alternation works same as logical OR.
- `(.*)` - Matches anything except newline.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i1W6e6/3/)

Comment: This works great. Any way to get it to catch `testing 1, 2, 3` as not a match? If not, I think I can work around that. (or better yet something like `testing one two three`)

Comment: well will it always be `testing` exact word ?

Comment: No, good point. Lets say `test one two three` for a test string.

Comment: You don't want to match `test`  at start of string right ?

Comment: Correct, that string would match to nothing ideally.

Comment: @aplassard check the updated one.if it full fill all cases let know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
^(this.*?)(test)?$
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    this                     'this'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    test                     'test'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific, I cannot assume lines will start with this or that test will end the string